# Given $y=\arccos(x)$ find $\arcsin(x)$ in terms of y

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given that $y = \arccos x$,  $ - 1 \le x \le 1\,and\,0 \le y \le \pi $, express $\arcsin x$ in terms of y.

The best I know how to do this is is:

$$\eqalign{
  & \cos y = x  \cr 
  & {\cos ^2}y + {\sin ^2}y = 1  \cr 
  & {\sin ^2}y = 1 - {\cos ^2}y  \cr 
  & \sin y = \sqrt {1 - {x^2}}   \cr 
  & \arcsin \left( {\sqrt {1 - {x^2}} } \right) = y \cr} $$

However this isn't what is asked for, How do I go about getting things in terms of y?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: $$x=\cos y=\sin\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-y\right)$$

Answer (score 4):

$$y = \arccos x \iff \cos y = x \iff x = \sin\left(\frac \pi 2 - y\right)\iff \arcsin x =  \left(\frac \pi 2 - y\right)$$

Comment: @Amzoti hehehehe... yes indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Draw a right triangle with angle $y$.  Let the hypotenuse be $1$ and the adjacent side $x$.  Now what is the opposite side?  What is $\sin y$?